# C / C++ Library for changing pitch without altering formant frequencies

Tags: audio

For a project I'm currently working on I would like to change the prosody * of a given voice sample. In other words, I need to pitch shift a voice sound without altering the formant frequencies that make up the characteristics of the voice. It's not a requirement for the system to run real-time.

Does anybody know any C or C++ (or actually, any other language) library which could achieve this?

Thanks!

* *Prosody is the pitch of a (human) voice.*

Comment: dunno of a library, but people [including me](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255966071_A_Detailed_Analysis_of_a_Time-Domain_Formant-Corrected_Pitch-Shifting_Algorithm) have written on the subject.  (and have coded it, too.)  try again at the DSP.SE if you have questions about the actual algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

Writing from the dsp.stackexchange.com side. Looks like the C++ [Rubber Band Library](http://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/) (GPL or buy a license) can do what you ask. Try the command line interface with option -F to preserve formants when pitch-shifting. I have found this library to give good quality results but did not try preserving formants.

Answer (score 0):

The [SoundTouch library](https://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) can alter the pitch without changing the tempo nor the sound quality. It has [LGPL](https://www.surina.net/soundtouch/license.html) licence (free for commercial use).

Here's the [source code](https://www.surina.net/soundtouch/sourcecode.html).

Finding documentation is not easy, but you can start by having a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930127/converting-a-short-from-soundtouch-audio-library-for-playback) and at the `include/SoundTouch.h` header file that can be found in the sources.